# Retrieve Facebook App ID for another app from Facebook API?

Tags: android, ios, facebook-graph-api, app-id, facebook-ads-api

We want to be able to retrieve the Facebook App ID for other apps (not our own), using the Facebook API or some other method. (Reason = we work with clients who sometimes don't know what a Facebook App ID is or how to find their own ;-)

For example... how can I find out the Facebook App ID for Candy Crush without having access to this developer account?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using 3rd party apps for that will be easiest.

For example: http://www.appdata.com/

There you can type in "Candy Crush Saga" in search box and application ID will be hidden in "View Application" URL for Candy Crush it's http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=210831918949520